# Sistema compruebe si hubo pagos del 1 al 5 de cada mes

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

es un sistema de pago de condominio y se requiere que muestre si los propietarios pagaron en el rango del 1 al 5 de cada mes tengo lo siguiente pero no me hace nada, se queda en blanco y la tabla si tiene datos

```js
<?php
session_start();
 require_once('../../conexion.php');
    $hoy = getdate();
  
    $begin = new DateTime( '2018-08-01' );
   
    $end = new DateTime( '2018-08-05' );
 
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

   
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    $alerta="";
   
    foreach($daterange as $date){
     
        $fecha_dia= $date->format("Ymd");
     
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pago_p WHERE fechadeposito ='$fecha_dia'"; 
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
       
            if(!empty($resultado["pago"])) {
            
                $alerta="si";
            }
        }

        if ($alerta=="si") {
            //despues del ciclo imprimimos la alerta para que en cada ciclo no la repita
            echo '<script> alert("No realizaste el pago en la fecha determinada"); </script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

La tabla su entidad se llama fechadeposito y su tipo es date

Comment: Necesitas saber día por día los pagos realizados? O sólo aquellos que se hicieron después del 5?

Comment: necesito que mensualmete se compruebe si un pago fue realizado del 1 al 5 de cada mes o despues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El planteo tiene un problema de lógica. Si lo que necesitás es los que pagaron después del 05 de cada mes no necesitás un intervalo, sino la última fecha y la príxma de comienzo del mes siguiente, en el caso de que fuera necesario hacer ese corte. Sino sólo haría falta la fecha de corte que es el 05 de cada mes.
Acá te dejo un ejemplo de ello, donde te dice el id de cada usuario que pagó fuera de término.

```
<?php
    //Conexion
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stackoverflow");
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    //Pasar año y mes para la consulta
    $periodo = $_GET['year'].'-'.$_GET['month'];

    //Formate de fecha
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
    $dateLimit = new DateTime($periodo.'-05');
    $dateLimit = $dateLimit->format("Y-m-d");

    $nextDate = new DateTime($periodo.'-01');
    $nextDate = $nextDate->modify('+1 month'); 
    $nextDate = $nextDate->format("Y-m-d");

    //Generar la consulta
    $sql = "SELECT id, fechadeposito, pago FROM pago_p WHERE fechadeposito > '$dateLimit' AND fechadeposito < '$nextDate'";

    if (
        //Validar que la consulta arroje resultados
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql) AND
        $resultado->num_rows > 0
    ){
        //Convertir cada resultado en un objeto
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_object()){
            printf('El usuario %s no realizó el pago a tiempo.', $row->id);
            echo "<br />";
        }       

    }else{
        echo 'Todos los usuarios pagaron a tiempo.';
    }

    //Liberar resultado
    $resultado->close();

    //Cerrar la conexión
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Espero que te sirva esta respuesta y cualquier duda la seguimos por los comentarios.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui lo que hay es un problema de logica... hasta donde los veo:

```
foreach($daterange as $date){

        $fecha_dia= $date->format("Y-m-d");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pago_p WHERE fechadeposito ='$fecha_dia'"; 
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

            if(!empty($resultado["pago"])) {
            // si entra aqui es por que el campo no esta vacio, por ende si se realizo el pago
//guardas en una variable donde dices si
                $alerta="si";
            }
        }
//luego cuanto termina preguntas
//obviamente si hubo pago la variable va a valer "si" entonces estas diciendo que no hizo el pago cuando en verdad si lo hizo
        if ($alerta=="si") {
            //despues del ciclo imprimimos la alerta para que en cada ciclo no la repita
            echo '<script> alert("No realizaste el pago en la fecha determinada"); </script>';
        }
    }
```

solucion: `if ($alerta !="si") {`
Asi niegas la condicion, osea dices "Si $`alert` es diferente de "si" entonces ahi si refererimo que no se hizo el pago"

**NOTA:** se adiciona guines al format, para que compare bien en BD

me cuentas como te fue....

Comment: realice lo que comentas pero muestra el alert estando o no la fecha en el rango

Comment: haz un echo y dime que imprime `$fecha_dia`

Comment: $fecha_dia si imprime la fecha que se realizo el pago el problema es los if`s

Comment: fecha dia no debe de imprimir eso, esa fecha debe imprimir varias todas la fechas que estan dentro del rango

Comment: no sera $date range lo que imprime eso? porque $fecha_dia esta en la consulta sql

Comment: `$fecha_dia` imprime las fechas del con formato dependiendo de `$date`

Comment: modifica esto `$fecha_dia= $date->format("Y-m-d");`

Comment: observa bien la que puse tiene `-` eso es lo que no esta dejando compara en la bd, ya que lo que mandas es algo `20180801` y en la bd debe estar `2018-08-01`

Comment: si ya lo coloque pero sigue mostrando la ventana emergente de que no pago a tiempo por mas que realice un pago el dia de hoy 01/09

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82597/discussion-between-srjj-and-anderson-rey).

Comment: ya que tienes las fechas de inicio y fin (dia 1 y dia 5 del mes) podrias utilizar una consulta de rango, tipo SELECT * FROM pago_p WHERE fechadeposito BETWEEN '$fecha_inicio' AND '$fecha_fin'.